# How to use "selection" in word to move the cursor with VBA code in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a "Userform" in excel which has a button.

When the button is clicked, VBA will open a Word document and find a string in Word table.

When finding the string, the cursor should move to the next row, but it doesn't work.

Here are my documents.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dhGoWxdaBxL2WmqsfFT6wllJ5z1d9csH/view?usp=sharing

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim path As String
    path = ThisWorkbook.path & "\範本.docx"
    'Debug.Print (path)

    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    WordApp.Documents.Open (path)
    WordApp.Visible = True
    WordApp.Activate
    WordApp.Selection.homekey unit:=6

    WordApp.Selection.Find.Execute FindText:="編號" ', Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindStop
    WordApp.Selection.MoveRight = 2
    WordApp.Selection.InsertAfter = LB_Num.Caption

End Sub
```

Comment: Use `WordApp.Selection.MoveRight  2` (remove the `=`).

Comment: I use `WordApp.Selection.Move Unit:=wdCell, Count:=1` but it still can't go to the next cells.

Comment: This is an English-language venue, and error messsages should be provided as plain text, not as images. Please use the [edit] link under the question to provide the English translation of the error message, or ask in a Japanese-language venue.

Comment: FWIW you're not using `MoveRight` correctly. I recommend you read up in the language reference how to use it. You need to either specify the parameter names or use the parameters in the correct order. My recommendation would be to use both the `Unit` as well as the `Count` parameters so that VBA is clear about what you want. All you tell it is `2` - but two *what*?

Comment: Have added a reference to Word in VBA project? Otherwise you should declare the constants you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I found this way can work.

```
Private Sub  CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim str As String
    str = TextBox1.Text
    Dim WordApp As Word.Application
    Set WordApp = New Word.Application

    WordApp.Documents.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\test.docm"
    WordApp.Visible = True

    WordApp.Selection.Find.Execute FindText:="編號"
    WordApp.Selection.Move Unit:=wdCell, Count:=1
    WordApp.Selection.InsertAfter str
    WordApp.Documents.Save

    Set WordApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

And need add Microsoft word Library first!

[image]